# How to use `groupby` to aggregate columns into dictionary so that new column contains that dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe that contains a `person`, `year`, and a bunch of `flag` containing columns, like below:

```
# sample dataframe
data = [["John Doe", 2018, True, False, True], ["Jane Doe", 2019, True, False, False]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["person", "year", "flag_1", "flag_2", "flag_3"])
df
```

```
     person     year   flag_1   flag_2  flag_3
0   John Doe    2018    True    False   True
1   Jane Doe    2019    True    False   False
```

I would like my final output to be a `groupby` where the `person` and `year` are retained, and a *new* column containing a dictionary of all the flag results is stored.

Something kind of like, but not quite like, this:

First: reshape

```
reshaped_df = pd.melt(
    df, id_vars=["person", "year"], value_vars=["flag_1", "flag_2", "flag_3"]
)
```

```
     person     year    variable value
0   John Doe    2018    flag_1   True
1   Jane Doe    2019    flag_1   True
2   John Doe    2018    flag_2   False
3   Jane Doe    2019    flag_2   False
4   John Doe    2018    flag_3   True
```

Second: Create dictionary

```
reshaped_df.set_index(["person", "year", "variable"]).T.to_dict("list")
```

```
{('John Doe', 2018, 'flag_1'): [True],
 ('Jane Doe', 2019, 'flag_1'): [True],
 ('John Doe', 2018, 'flag_2'): [False],
 ('Jane Doe', 2019, 'flag_2'): [False],
 ('John Doe', 2018, 'flag_3'): [True],
 ('Jane Doe', 2019, 'flag_3'): [False]}
```

**except** I want my output to look like this:

```
    person      year    flag_dict
0   John Doe    2018    {'flag_1': True, 'flag_2': False, 'flag_3': True}
1   Jane Doe    2019    {'flag_1': True, 'flag_2': False, 'flag_3': False}
```

Is this possible? If so how can it be done? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a complex reshape, simply use [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html)

```
cols = list (df.filter(like='flag_'))

out = (
 df.drop(columns=cols)
   .assign(flag_dict=df[cols].to_dict('records'))
 )
```

Output:

```
     person  year                                           flag_dict
0  John Doe  2018   {'flag_1': True, 'flag_2': False, 'flag_3': True}
1  Jane Doe  2019  {'flag_1': True, 'flag_2': False, 'flag_3': False}
```